# Implementing OWIN SSO in an Existing MVC4 App (while retaining option of forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, owin, ws-federation

We have an existing application based on .Net 4.5 / MVC 4.

The application currently uses forms authentication, so we have authentication mode="Forms" in our web.config.

We would like to retain this functionality, but also give some customers the option of logging in using federated identity, and plan on using OWIN to accomplish this.

The problem is, how do we code our web.config to satisfy both types of authentication?

Thanks.

Comment: Broadly speaking when you have authenticated the user using your deferated identity solution you create a forms auth ticket.

Comment: Can you expand on that - what do I put in web.config to satisfy the requirements for both the authentication mode we have now and federated identity?

Comment: Not really your question is extremely broad, but specifically with the web config i suspect you will leave it as forms auth, you simply generate the forms authorisation ticket manually after you have authenticated manually against a different provider.

Comment: So you are saying that it is possible to use OWIN to accomplish this without changing my web.config?

Comment: can we make API based federated login or loosely coupled or configurable ? since we have multiple client who is using our enterprise application, many are using form authentication and some are using federated login like okta , openId etc.